# Tkinter Image not displaying in label or canvas

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas, tkinter-label

Here is my code actually creating these labels or canvases:

```
class FrameBanner(tk.Frame):
    """

    """
    def __init__(self, root, color_black, color_yellow, width, height):

        # Initialize from parent
        super(FrameBanner, self).__init__(root)

        # # Left 1 Banner
        # self.banner_1 = tk.Canvas(master=self, width=width*0.8, height=height, bg=color_yellow)
        self.image_1 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images_2/logo_here.png").resize((round(width*0.7), round(height*0.9)), Image.NEAREST))
        # self.banner_1.create_image(10, 10, anchor="w", image=self.image_1)
        # self.banner_1.image = self.image_1
        self.banner_1 = tk.Label(master=self, image=self.image_1)
        self.banner_1.image = self.image_1

        # # Right 2 Banner
        # self.banner_2 = tk.Canvas(master=self, width=width*0.2, height=height, bg=color_black)
        self.image_2 = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("images_2/logo_here.png").resize((round(width*0.15), round(height*0.9)), Image.NEAREST))
        # self.banner_2.create_image(width*0.2, 10, anchor="w", image=self.image_2)
        # self.banner_2.image = self.image_IMS
        self.banner_2 = tk.Label(master=self, image=self.image_2)
        self.banner_2.image = self.image_2

        # Grid Layout
        self.banner_1.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='w')
        self.banner_2.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='e')
```

Here is my code where it is called:

```
        ## Banner
        self.frm_banner_height = height*0.2
        self.frm_banner = tk.Frame(master=self.frm_pregen, width=self.frm_pregen_width, height=self.frm_banner_height)
        self.FrameBanner = FrameBanner(self.frm_banner, color_black, color_yellow, self.frm_pregen_width, self.frm_banner_height)
```

I then later do:

```
self.frm_banner.grid(column=0, row=0)
```

This is what it looks like, with the corner where I want the two images to be empty:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTZxU.png)

Any suggestions?

Comment: after initialization variables that are not attributes of that instance get garbage collected (it should be `self.image_STAR` and `self.image_IMS`) [Why does Tkinter image not show up if created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function)

Comment: I have tried this, not I also save it in self.banner_X.image

Comment: Just tried it again and it did not work. Updated question code so this is not suggested again.

Comment: What is `self.frm_pregen`? A Frame?

Comment: You did not call any layout function on `self.FrameBanner`.

Comment: Yes Derek, self.frm_pregen is a frame

Comment: acw1668, I call one on self.frm_banner later if that is what you are asking. self.FrameBanner is used to edit the self.frm_banner object so I didn't think I could nor needed to grid self.FrameBanner

Comment: @SamuelOwen No you need to call on `self.FrameBanner` as well and it will work.

Comment: Please write an answer and I will try your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you did not call any layout function on `self.FrameBanner`:

```
...
self.FrameBanner.pack() # or whatever layout manager you want
self.frm_banner.grid(column=0, row=0)
...
```

Comment: Well, the other issue would have been not making those images an attribute of the instance but OP edited the question and corrected this (don't know if that's good or bad but that would have been part of the issue (I think))

Comment: Matiiss, I had already tried that and I also do that separately self.banner_X.image.